# Format Date Number from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, odbc

Not sure if I should edit this question or just ask another question in a different post. I am having a hard time doing the reverse of what I originally asked. How do I get the "date number" in php. I want to assign the current date number to a variable to so I can use it in my query to compare what is already in the database.

> I can not see the SQL Server database
>   but I am connecting to it using ODBC
>   and PHP on a Linux box. I was told
>   that the field "meeting_start" was a
>   "Date Number". When I get the value of
>   the "meeting_start" the format looks
>   like this.
>
> ```
> 2010-08-24 20:00:00.000
> ```
>
> I need both the date and time but for
>   different parts of my function.  Is
>   there a way to extract the data for
>   the date and save to a variable and
>   then extract the data for the time and
>   save to a different variable. Below is
>   me trying to take a stab at it.
>
> ```
> $time_date_data = "2010-08-24 20:00:00.000"
>
> $meeting_date = get_date($time_date_data); 
>
> $meeting_time = get_time($time_date_data);
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
$meeting_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($time_date_data));
$meeting_time = date('H:i', strtotime($time_date_data));
```

For `$time_date_data = '2010-08-24 20:00:00.000'`, you'll get:

```
$meeting_date = '2010-08-24';
$meeting_time = '20:00';
```

You can change the format by changing the first argument to `date()` according to the docs...

Comment: Maybe not the case, but calling a function twice is slower then calling it once and using a variable :)

Answer (score 2):

Two options here. You can do it either on the SQL Server side or the application side.

**For SQL**: If you want the date only, in format YYYY/MM/DD, do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]
```

If you want the time only, in format HH:MM:SS, do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

**Alternatively**, you can do this all in PHP by using the "date" function, something like:

```
$theDate = date("YYYY/MM/DD", strtotime($theFullDate))
$theTime = date("HH:MM:SS", strtotime($theFullDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$stamp=strtotime("2010-08-24 20:00:00.000");
$date=date("Y-m-d",$stamp);
$time=date("H:i:s",$stamp);
```

or:

```
list($date,$time)=explode(" ","2010-08-24 20:00:00.000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$meeting_date = substr($time_date_data, 0, -13);

$meeting_time = substr($time_date_data,11);
```